# Исходник блога на wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Приветствую

Господа, есть ли в интернете исходники блогов на wordpress? Не имею ввиду 'зайти в гугль', получить 3 высших образования по wp, а допустим какие то настроенные блоги, со всем включенным так сказать. Что бы он был скажем так модифицирован от оригинала минимально. Поставил - и можно заниматься блогингом.. Посты, посты посты..

p.s. т.е. ищу такое готово решение, залил базу и файлы - все готово (дизайн - неважен). Интересует есть ли такое. Вот wp конечно хорош но охото решение для блога так сказать, без всяких установок плагинов (что бы все было уже внитри)

Comment: качаете официальный дистрибутив и ставите его. Все. Установить ВП дело 2х минут, там интерфейс довольно дружелюбный.

Comment: дык.. нет! Интересует именно какая ни будь сборка wp. Там, где есть маленький блог, со всем поставленным. Так как в инете делают блоги. Согласитесь чистый wp отличается от сделанного блога. Вот охота увидеть пару сборок. Как люди делают так сказать. Продукт 'все в одном'.

Comment: @mixalef вы что-то путаете

Comment: WP в первую очередь, движок для блога. Вы видимо что то путаете.
Установите оригинал, и публикуйте сообщения в свой блог. Там все нужное из коробки стоит.

Comment: Установил оригинал.. действительно, ничего не путаю. Установленный оригинал, после очень долгих разглядываний - отличается от готового блога, хотя бы тем, что готовые блоги как то более менее приспособлены для работы. О харабабр и гитхаб как обычно во всем своем разннобразии решений ни содержат ни одного. Собственно вот и подумал может у кого есть пара полезных ссылок на такие ресурсы

Comment: @mixalef вы не могли бы (для начала) четко описать, что вообще ищется-то?

Comment: Да обычный простой блог, переделанный кем-либо, под себя. в идеале 2-3 примера таких блогов. Не с целью упереть и у себя повесить, в просто по изучать. Без всякой хрени типа Хелловорлд, а допустим 10-20 постов что бы было, с картинками видео, статьями оформленными. Что то, что кому то пригодилось и используется. Попросил самое простое.. нет, я неправ (

Comment: http://blogmvc.com http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90802/simple-free-php-blog-engine-easy-to-redesign http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/08/29/10-weblog-engines-reviewed/ http://chyrp.net/ http://www.nibbleblog.com/ http://textpress.shameerc.com/

Но вообще вордпресс наверняка наиболее функционально насыщенный. При всей убогости его кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть про то что вы говорите, такие модифицированные версии поставляются вместе с запиленным под корень шаблоном со всякими дополнительными настроечками касательно шаблона, как пример вот [гля](http://themeforest.net/item/chocolate-wp-responsive-photography-theme/full_screen_preview/299901).

Answer (score 1):

Свежеустановленный wordpress это и есть сферический standalone-блог в вакууме, заточенный под то что-бы не заморачиваясь техническими вопросами сесть и начать строчить нетленки и постить котиков. Уже нескольким знакомым гуманитариям его подсовывал и они его осваивали без проблем, практически сходу.

Если в чистом WP тебе чего-то не хватает — пойми чего и найди для этого плагин (скорее всего их уже есть штуки три, для чего-бы то нибыло :). Установить плагин в WP проще чем программу в винде, «плагины» > «добавить новый» > вводишь название плагина или ключевые слова. С темати то-же самое.

Если нужен какой-то контент, например для тестирования тем, набей его. Делов-то. http://ru.lipsum.com/ для текстов (для русских текстов http://referats.yandex.ru/). Для картинок http://lorempixel.com/, для видео ютуб и первые попавшиеся ролики. На набивку десятка другого постов уйдёт времени не больше чем ушло на выклянчивание готового решения тут.